# How to properly implement adding a new record into Elasticsearch using Spring Boot?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

Getting started with Spring Boot / Spring Data / Elasticsearch application.
ES -> 6.1

Have a simple repository:

```
public interface BusinessMetadataRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<BusinessMetadata, Long> {
    List<BusinessMetadata> findByName(String name);

    List<BusinessMetadata> findById(Long id);

}
```

And a Business Object:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "bsn", type = "mtd", shards = 1)
public class BusinessMetadata {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BusinessMetadata(Long id, String name) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BusinessMetadata() {

    }
}
```

Elastic Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.discover.harmony.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public NodeBuilder nodeBuilder() {
        return new NodeBuilder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws IOException {
        File tmpDir = File.createTempFile("elastic", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));
        System.out.println("Temp directory: " + tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
        Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings =
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("http.enabled", "true") // 1
                        .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
                        .put("path.data", new File(tmpDir, "data").getAbsolutePath()) // 2
                        .put("path.logs", new File(tmpDir, "logs").getAbsolutePath()) // 2
                        .put("path.work", new File(tmpDir, "work").getAbsolutePath()) // 2
                        .put("path.home", tmpDir); // 3



        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder()
                .local(true)
                .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
                .node()
                .client());
    }
}
```

My Rest Controller for doing search works fine:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/search")
public class SearchResource {

    @Autowired
    BusinessMetadataRepository businessMetadataRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/name/{text}")
    public List<BusinessMetadata> searchName(@PathVariable final String text) {
        return businessMetadataRepository.findByName(text);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<BusinessMetadata> searchAll() {
        List<BusinessMetadata> businessMetadataList = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<BusinessMetadata> businessMetadata = businessMetadataRepository.findAll();
        businessMetadata.forEach(businessMetadataList::add);
        return businessMetadataList;
    }


}
```

My Rest Controller for doing save:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/save")
public class SaveResource {

    @Autowired
    BusinessMetadataRepository businessMetadataRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/name/{text}")
    public void Save(String text) {
        businessMetadataRepository.save(new BusinessMetadata((long)99, text));
    }
}
```

When I test the save using Postman, I get this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1514325625996,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/rest/save/name/new-1"
}
```

What changes do I need to make in order to properly configure this project to support inserting new documents?

Comment: Well from a fast look your code seems fine , but from Postman you are trying to test the `/rest/save` endpoint using POST method although you have defined it as GET along with the `PathVariable` `String text`,  the error that spring throws is quite obvious as there is not any method accepting POST type , so you really want to change the *project* or your test case / front end client ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from AntJavaDev, I have modified my controller in the following way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/save")
public class SaveResource {

    @Autowired
    BusinessMetadataRepository businessMetadataRepository;

    @PostMapping("/name/{text}")
    public void Save(@PathVariable String text) {
        BusinessMetadata mtd = businessMetadataRepository.save(new BusinessMetadata(text));
    }
}
```

The 2 key changes are: replace @GetMapping with @PostMapping, and include @PathVariable as a parameter qualifier.

Now it works as expected